# Exit vi on serial console

Tags: router, debian

I have this ubiquiti edge router that I have connected to using a serial adapter and Putty.  After entering the vi editor, I find no way to exit.  Nothing I have tried so far gets into command mode, esc, etc.  Is serial (or serial+putty) an odd one out here and missing some vital command?  Or is this some bug in the router?

Comment: the Colon (:) should drop you to command mode.  I dont use VI much but when I'm forced to here is what I use for a cheat sheet: http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print `:q!` to force exit without saving or `:wq` to save changes (w like write and q like quit)

Take a look for basic vi-commands: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html